# Apply SailsJS policy to multilevel url

Tags: routes, sails.js, policy

I'm trying to apply a policy to a route. The route is `/model/:id/duration`. How can I apply a policy to that in the `config/policies.js` file? I tried the following but didn't work:

**config/policies.js**:

```
'model': {
    '*': 'isAdmin',        // works fine
    '*/duration': true,    // doesn't work. 'isAdmin' is still applied.
    '*': {
        'duration': true,  // doesn't work
    },
    ':id/duration': true,  // doesn't work
}
```

Comment: What is duration? Is it an association or just a model attribute?

Comment: Policies are used to control access of controller function not to routes

Comment: @zabware /duration is a route I wrote to run a controller function.

Comment: @khushalbokadey so I would have to apply a policy to the controller function instead of the route? I think that's the solution actually.

Comment: @AskYous Yes. Bascially policies are defined to deny access to controller and its methods.